# could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [email_address\" of relation \"users]; nested exception

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm getting this error while adding to the candidates table.candidates table extends the users table. Email and password columns come from this table.I think there is a problem with the database, I am using postreSql. What would be the reason ?

User Table

```
package com.example.hrmsdemo.entities.concretes;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="users",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

Candidate Table

```
package com.example.hrmsdemo.entities.concretes;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="candidates",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"identity_number"})})
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class Candidate extends User {


    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull
    private String first_name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "identity_number")
    private String identity_number;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birth_date;


}
```

Error

```
2021-05-26 15:59:53.230  WARN 24964 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2021-05-26 15:59:53.230 ERROR 24964 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HATA: null value in column "email_address" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint
  Ayrıntı: Hata veren satır (7, null, 123414, veyselhim@gmail.com) içeriyor.
2021-05-26 15:59:53.245 ERROR 24964 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [email_address" of relation "users]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

Comment: Why did you add a Microsoft SQL Server tag to a PosgreSQL question? I removed the inappropriate tag and added the correct one to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: thank you sir , i havent seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you really map `User#email` to a column named `email_address`?  That is the column that the database is complaining about but you do not show a mapping to that column.

Assuming that is true, you have defined that this attribute should be non-null which also seems to be how the database is defined.  This would suggest that you are trying to save a User and did not set its email property.

Or maybe you really have not mapped that column and so Hibernate never tries to write to it.  Hard to tell from just what you have given us.

Comment: The name in the database and the name i wrote in the code were not the same, thank you